# Upgraded to latest Python on Win 7 Pro

Tags: python

My PC used to have an ealier version of Python, with a few .py scripts that was excecuted from a .bat file, and that .bat file was excecuted by another program.

It was time to learn Python, so I upgraded to the latest version, 3.6.5
At first I thought by installing the latest version, it will obveride the older versions. But found out when open the .py file with Edit with IDLE, the older version's number appeared in the window within the script.
So I uninstalled all older versions of Python, and re-installed again the latest version.
But now there is no Edit with IDLE on the context menu.

I am vey new to Python, I had the initial scripts written by someone else long time ago using the older version of Python.

So How do I get the Edit with IDLE back on the context menu, is it something I have download ?

Thanks

Comment: I had the same situation some couple of days ago (but with python 2.7), my simple hack was to create a new windows user and start using python from there, and it worked fine.

Comment: IDLE is linked to a Python interpreter, I'm pretty sure.  You need to use the correct IDLE executable. You could always just use any text editor...

Answer (score 0):

On windows, you need to set the path to the new python executable `C:\Python36` (or wherever you installed python) to your PATH *environmental variable* as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4855685/6060083), including screenshots:

```
My Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > PATH
```

Restart PC afterwards and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

Configure *environmental variable* as sudonym's answer.

Solution 2:

Use a IDE as *PyCharm* or *PyDev* for coding.